# Let G be a simple graph so that between any two vertices v and w...

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let G be a simple graph so that between any two vertices v and w, there is a unique simple path that begins at v and ends at w. Prove that G is bipartite (by induction of n).

I don't understand how to solve this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$G$ cannot have cycles. Indeed, proceed by contradiction (which is essentially equivalent to showing the contrapositive of a statement) and assume there exists a cycle. Let $v$ and $w$ be two distinct vertices in this cycle. For there to be a cycle, there must be two disjoint paths composing the cycle each from $v$ to $w$. To see why this is, we can just list out the vertices of the cycle starting from $v$ until we get back to $v$. Suppose the list of vertices is 
$$(v, u_1, u_2, u_3, \cdots, w, u_k, u_{k + 1}, \cdots, u_m, v)$$
A cycle does not visit any vertex except its starting point twice, so indeed the two disjoint paths connecting $v$ and $w$ are 
$$P_1 = (v, u_1, u_2, u_3, \cdots, w) ~~ \text{ and } ~ ~ P_2 = (v, u_m, \cdots, u_{k + 1}, u_k, w)$$
which is a contradiction of the assumption that the path connecting $v$ and $w$ is unique.

To show that this graph is bipartite, note that a graph is bipartite if and only if it has no odd cycles. But this graph has *no* cycles, so it clearly has no odd cycles. Therefore, it is bipartite.

If you insist on using induction, you can first show the base case, then note in the inductive step that a new vertex can only be connected to vertices from at most one partition (call it $X$) of the bipartite graph in order to preserve its acyclic property. If this is the case, then the newly added vertex will be part of the partition that is not $X$ in the bipartite graph.